# Creating json file in Symfony 2

Tags: json, symfony

Hi I've created json object like that:

```
{"ask":[{"rate":"2110.00000000","amount":"2.00000000","price":"4220.00000000","degree":0.2},{"rate":"1800.00000000","amount":"5.00000000","price":"9000.00000000","degree":0.5},{"rate":"20.00000000","amount":"8.00000000","price":"160.00000000","degree":0.8}],"bid":[{"rate":"1700.00000000","amount":"0.50000000","price":"1700.00000000","degree":0.5}]}
```

and I would like to create a file and put json to it, how can I do it?

Comment: How did you "create" the above JSON? Consider saving it into a file?

Comment: It is repsone from database and I use json_encode() function. I need to save it to file, because it will improve access time from ajax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You could use the Filesystem Component, and the dumpFile function.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html#dumpfile)

Let's say that you have `$json` which contains your json string.

```
$fs = new \Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem();

try {
    $fs->dumpFile('path/to/my/file.json', $json);
}
catch(IOException $e) {
}
```

Or you could use PHP functions, such as [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: And a path should be for example "AcmeDemoBunle/Data/my.json ?

Comment: Nop. This is the path on the filesystem. For example 'c:\\Windows' (absolute path) or 'tmp' (relative path). You can use thinks like $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir(); to get the Symfony2 dir